# Fridgidaire Microwave sometimes starts running when door is closed

Tags: microwave-oven

*Model No: FMV152KSA*

My Frigidaire microwave has an intermittent problem where after closing the door it immediately starts running....so I never hit Start.

Sometimes this means it runs for a few seconds and stops and other times it seems to run for much longer before I stop it by opening and closing the door again.

When it runs, the LCD seems fine but if the cook time doesn't count down, the spinner spins but it doesn't heat up and doesnt stop if I hit Stop either.

It's intermittent, so I may be able to open and close the door with no problem 5 times in a row and the 6th time it just starts running when closed.

Or I may set a cook time of 2 minutes, open the door, closes the door, it starts running but the remaining time is stuck at 2 minutes.

Most of the problems I see online are regarding the door switches when the Microwave runs when the door is opened or doesn't run when the door is closed.  I wasn't sure if my problem is most likely the switches or something else maybe?

Also, I see instructional videos online and some mention discharging the capacitor before proceeding as a safety measure and others don't.  Are the ones that don't foolish or is it because replacing the door switches poses no real risk from the capacitor?

Comment: If your microwave has capacitors in it, assume that they're holding a charge and are prepared to zap _you_ at any moment! Provide the make/model of your microwave, that will help those more knowledgeable than I...

Comment: why would you think that the door switch is the problem?

Comment: Is there still time on the timer? Is it a mechanical timer? Your start button may be being triggered when you close the door. Zero the time and it should not start. The door switch allows the unit to turn on. So closing the door with time on the counter could indicate a sticky start button not a door problem.

Comment: @FreeMan model number added, sorry

Comment: @EdBeal The timer isn't counting down, it's an electronic timer.  So for example the time on the clock would show 1:05 PM, I'm not preparing to start any cooking, I simply open the door and close it and half of the time the microwave starts and no time is counting down

Comment: @jsotola I thought because it occurs when the door closes it was the switches but I'm getting the impression that would be incorrect

Comment: door switches stop the microwave oven from operating when the door is opened ... if one of the door switches was defective, then the oven would never turn on

Comment: "*So for example the time on the clock would show 1:05 PM, I'm not preparing to start any cooking, I simply open the door and close it and half of the time the microwave starts and no time is counting down*" The time on the clock is not the timer.  Why are opening and closing the door if you are not using it to cook something?

Comment: That's a logic error on the microcontroller. Given there's no countdown, it's severally malfunctioning and should probably be immediately unplugged and replaced. While there's probably a hardware door close safety switch that will keep you from getting zapped when open, it still could run all night and possibly ignore failsafe programming, possibly leading to a fire at worst and a high power bill at best.

Comment: @dandavis but it has only ever happened when I close the door, not on its own

Comment: I agree with @dandavis with no time on the display and it starting is a serious failure. A call to the manufacturer with a serious failure like this might get you a new one. I would suggest taking a video showing the display and closing the door and it turning on. It’s worth a try. The door interlock should kill power to the magnetron if that was to also fail they could have a lawsuit on there hands.

Comment: does it start cooking, or does it just start the noise?

Comment: @jasen just the noise

Comment: well that's not so dangerous. have there been insects inside workings of it?

Comment: @jasen I don't think so